# Game on facebook causing non-stop refresh on Chrome

Tags: php, html, facebook, google-chrome

I am working on the development of a game due to be released on FaceBook. Working through the game i have tested it on three web browsers, FireFox Release: 25.0.1, Internet Explorer Release: 10.0.11 and Google Chrome Release: 31.0.1650.57 m.

The game i am making is not very complex, it being developed through HTML 5 and JavaScript. I have uploaded the game and all the associated files to my host and have begun testing the game through FaceBook Development tool, however (aside from spacebar (being a key to shoot) being annoying due to it being a shortcut to the bottom of the page ) Chrome is the only web browser i have tried that is causing an issue. But here is the kicker, as a standard HTML file (without the facebook php code) it works fine, but since uploading index.php ( a copy of the HTML file but with the neccessary login php code) Chrome keeps refreshing the page. I google searched for a good while and found a post on stack and the OP's answer suggesting that the facebook SDK should be downloaded to the most recent version, i did that so that is not the problem. I checked to insure that the app_namespace, app_id and app_secret is correct, it is. So i am kind of stumped

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
require 'server/fb-php-sdk/facebook.php';

    $app_id = '#';
    $app_secret = '#';
    $app_namespace = '#';
    $app_url = 'https://apps.facebook.com/' . $app_namespace . '/';
    $scope = 'email,publish_actions';

    // Init the Facebook SDK
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
         'appId'  => $app_id,
         'secret' => $app_secret,
));

// Get the current user
$user = $facebook->getUser();

// If the user has not installed the app, redirect them to the Login Dialog
if (!$user) {
        $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
        'scope' => $scope,
        'redirect_uri' => $app_url,
        ));

        print('<script> top.location.href=\'' . $loginUrl . '\'</script>');
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<title>My Game</title>
</head>



<body>

<!-- The canvas for the panning background -->

<canvas id="background" width="500" height="600" z-index="0">
Your browser does not support canvas. Please try again with a different browser.
</canvas>
<canvas id="enemyCanvas" width="501" height="601" z-index="1">
Your browser does not support canvas. Please try again with a different browser.
</canvas>
<canvas id="introCanvas" width="501" height="601" z-index="2">
Your browser does not support canvas. Please try again with a different browser.
</canvas>
<div id="button"><strong>PLAY GAME</strong></div>
<div id="button1"><strong>INSTRUCTIONS</strong></div>
<div id="LevelUpSpeedButton"><strong></strong></div>
<div id="LevelUpDamageButton"><strong></strong></div>
<div id="SoundButton"></div>
<div id="iframe">
<iframe src="#" height="600" width="240"></iframe>
</div>

<script src="Game.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The refresh is only ever an issue on facebook.
In additional, i understand that iframe the seamless property does not work on Chrome and I.E. i believe, so i had removed it. Assistance, as always, is appreciated.

EDIT: I have failed to mention several things. I have used the debug tools Firebug on FireFox and Chromes own script debugging tool. They are not showing up any errors with the JavaScript file and just for the sake of giving readers an idea of how small the game is, the game has 1052 lines of code, doesn't use JQuery or any additional libraries has been tested in Chrome debugging to perform on average 16 requests  load: 719ms DOMcontentLoaded:72ms

Comment: I decided that it would probably be best if i checked if removing iframe from the PHP file would change the outcome. It did, the page loads perfectly without the iframe attached. Disappointing in my opinion but i guess i will have to do without the iframe.